# DB Upgrade/Update Error - no such field, unknown column

Tags: upgrade, error

We're using CiviCRM 5.31.0 on Joomla 3.9.23.

Even with all CiviCRM extensions disabled, we get similar errors like this when doing a DB Upgrade, installing, enabling, and disabling extensions.

How do we resolve this?

```
#0 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(148): CRM_Core_Error::backtrace()
#1 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(921): CRM_Core_Error::handle(Object(DB_Error))
#2 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB.php(997): PEAR_Error->__construct("DB Error: no such field", -19, 16, (Array:2), "\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...")
#3 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(575): DB_Error->__construct(-19, 16, (Array:2), "\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...")
#4 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/PEAR.php(223): PEAR::_raiseError(Object(DB_mysqli), NULL, -19, 16, (Array:2), "\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...", "DB_Error", TRUE)
#5 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1925): PEAR->__call("raiseError", (Array:7))
#6 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(936): DB_common->raiseError(-19, NULL, NULL, "\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...", "1054 ** Unknown column 'workflow_name' in 'field list'")
#7 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/mysqli.php(406): DB_mysqli->mysqliRaiseError()
#8 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/common.php(1231): DB_mysqli->simpleQuery("\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...")
#9 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(2696): DB_common->query("\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...")
#10 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/packages/DB/DataObject.php(1829): DB_DataObject->_query("\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...")
#11 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(457): DB_DataObject->query("\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...")
#12 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/DAO.php(1563): CRM_Core_DAO->query("\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = '<!DOCTYPE html PUBL...", TRUE)
#13 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/MessageTemplates.php(314): CRM_Core_DAO::executeQuery("\n            UPDATE civicrm_msg_template SET msg_html = %1 WHERE id IN (38,37)", (Array:1))
#14 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Incremental/General.php(157): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_MessageTemplates->updateTemplates()
#15 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Form.php(808): CRM_Upgrade_Incremental_General::updateMessageTemplate("<p>This system uses MySQL/MariaDB v5.6.41-84.1-log. You may proceed with the ...", "5.30.alpha1")
#16 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(108): CRM_Upgrade_Form->setPreUpgradeMessage("<p>This system uses MySQL/MariaDB v5.6.41-84.1-log. You may proceed with the ...", "5.29.1", "5.31.0")
#17 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Upgrade/Page/Upgrade.php(57): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->runIntro()
#18 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(312): CRM_Upgrade_Page_Upgrade->run((Array:2), NULL)
#19 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(68): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#20 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:2))
#21 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(121): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:2))
#22 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#23 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_c...")
#24 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/components/com_c...")
#25 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#26 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
#27 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(196): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#28 /home/fxx/public_html/fxx/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#29 {main}
```

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!  The missing column is `workflow_name`.  That should have been added by the upgrade to 5.26.  Check the table definition for `civicrm_msg_template` - does it have a `workflow_name` column?  If not, go back and look at your logs for the upgrade to 5.26 and see if there are any errors there.

Also, do you have logging enabled?  If so disable and re-enable that at `Administer > System Settings > Misc > Logging` to make sure the logging table schema is correct.